# Z axis issue with Ramps 1.4

Tags: marlin, printer-building, ramps-1.4

I just installed a Ramps 1.4 board on to my Anet A8. Everything worked as it should except for the Z axis motors. The Ramps board I have contains two headers for each Z axis motor.

When both motors are connected, one of the motors squeals like something awful. When I disconnect one motor it turns smooth as butter. I have tried this for both motors and when only one is connected it works as it should but does not with both.

Has anyone experienced this? Is there a simple remedy for this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you orient the plug correctly?  Flipping the plug of a correctly wired motor will reverse the direction on RAMPS.  It may be that you had them fighting each other or the current isn't high enough on the driver.

Comment: The plugs are oriented properly. The threaded rods are also removed so the motors shouldn't be interacting with each other. I even swapped out the driver board with another and I still get the grinding sound from the servos when they are both connected. Does the potentiometer on the driver raise/lower the current?

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue. The steps were set way to high. I lowered my steps to 500 and the steppers seem to perform as they should.